# Multer (Nodejs) Images not loaded OR images was gone when accessing my websites (.herokuapp.com)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, multer

The images did not load OR missing when I checked it after some days, it was displaying an alternative image instead. Here's my website :

https://klasifikasi-ptpnx-djoembang.herokuapp.com

this is the `heroku logs -t` (I'm only showing the image request)

```
...
019-07-29T13:31:20.944287+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/img/profilePicture/1651502001111882.jpg" 
host=klasifikasi-ptpnx-djoembang.herokuapp.com 
request_id=579af663-0e38-4f4e-8593-3e8aae615a2e 
fwd="116.206.40.124" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms 
status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
...
```

it was fine for a day but if I try to access it again on the next day, the images were gone. I can't see any errors. It seems like whenever the status code are 300, it would not displaying I guess?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone through https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted ?

As per Heroku documentation, 
the Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

Comment: Well that's explain everyhing. Thank your very much!!